# Query to select all workshops a user is not registered for

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to make a query to select all of the workshop information that the user isn't registered for. I want to have all the data with 1 query.

This is the : workshops table
[image: The workshops table]
The : registrations table
[image: The registrations table]
The : workshop_rounds table
[image: The workshop_rounds table]

Hopefully some of you guys could help me.
Thanks in advance!

I've tried this query, but it is not what i want, it is close but not fully.

```
SELECT * FROM `workshop_rounds` WHERE `id` != ALL (SELECT `workshop_round_id` FROM `registrations` WHERE `user_id` = 1) AND `workshop_id` != ALL (SELECT `workshop_id` FROM `workshop_rounds` WHERE `workshop_id`= ALL (SELECT `workshop_round_id` FROM `registrations` WHERE `user_id` = 1))
```

The result is:
[image]

But now i also want to not get the other rounds with the same workshop_id as the round the user is registered for. Hopefully you understand me.

Comment: What have you tried so far and where do you stuck?

Comment: I have tried this

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT *
FROM workshops w
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM registrations r
    JOIN "workshop_rounds" wr ON r."workshop_round_id" = wr.id
    WHERE wr.workshop_id = w.id
          AND r."user_id" = 1
);
```

and maybe more concise `NOT IN`

```
SELECT *
FROM workshops w
WHERE w.id NOT IN
(
    SELECT wr.workshop_id
    FROM registrations r
    JOIN "workshop_rounds" wr ON r."workshop_round_id" = wr.id
    WHERE r."user_id" = 1
);
```

Answer (score 1):

For a single user, I would approach this with `not exists`:

```
select w.*
from workshops w
where not exists (select 1
                  from registrations r
                  where r.workshop_id = w.id and
                        r.user_id = THE USER ID
                 );
```

Comment: This is not wat i want to get back, Thanks for your try tho

Answer (score 0):

Try this one to fetch all workshops that user not registered

```
select ws.* from workshops ws 
       where ws.id not in (select w.id from workshops w, workshop_rounds wr, registrations r 
                where r.workshop_round_id = wr.id and wr.workshop_id=w.id and r.user_id = THE_USER_ID);
```